# Google Analytics (Enhanced Ecommerce )

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics-api

I implemented Google Analytics Enhanced E-Commerce , but unable to track it on Google Analytics Account.
 I applied all required settings in my account.
 I can see there screen and events but about Enhanced E-Commerce it showing blank. Please any one give me an idea how can I see it there.

```
- (void)googleAnalyticsEnhancedEcommerceTracking
{
//  Ecommerce GA
GAIEcommerceProduct *productForGA = [[GAIEcommerceProduct alloc] init];
[productForGA setId:1122];
[productForGA setName:@"Chess Board"];
[productForGA setCategory:@"Game"];
[productForGA setBrand:@"Brand Name"];
[productForGA setVariant:2];
[productForGA setCustomDimension:1 value:([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:EmailAddressKey])?[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:EmailAddressKey]:@""];

GAIEcommerceProductAction *action = [[GAIEcommerceProductAction alloc] init];
[action setAction:kGAIPAClick];
[action setProductActionList:@"Buy It"];
GAIDictionaryBuilder *builder = [GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView];
[builder addProduct:productForGA];
[builder setProductAction:action];
[builder build];
}
```

but I am unable to see loaded data on screen

[image]

Comment: I've set tracker outside of this block, but builder are working or not that is my problem.

Comment: Have you enabled enhanced e-commerce tracking?

Comment: Yes I enabled it. but not able to verify whether its working or not...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but a general topic on Debugging Google Analytics.

I'm not familiar with the code but the debugging process for GA is the same:

1. Is the data leaving the browser? If not, there is a coding or configuration error.

   Use the Chrome extension, dataSlayer, to view Enhanced Ecommerce data - it shows `(contains enhanced ecommerce)` when appropriate.

   If the data isn't leaving the browser, use Chrome's "Google Analytics Debugger" extension. It loads the debug version of the API and prints out GA debug info to the console - hopefully that will show you where things are failing
2. Is it reaching GA as seen in Real Time Reporting?

   RT shows data after it is filtered so if no data is seen in RT, use a "No Filters" View (Profile) that has no filters.

   One cannot see Enhanced Ecomm data in RT but one can see the Events or Pageviews carrying the data.
3. Is it reaching GA but being blocked by a filter?

   Fix the filter